# Mysql query to Query Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to take this SQL query to a query in Laravel Query Builder. It is important that the result be of type Query Builder. Please if you can help me.

```
SELECT MAX(sub.total) as total, sub.vendedor
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(id) as total, vendedor  
    FROM data_reports dr
    GROUP BY vendedor
) sub
```

I have the following but I couldn't go any further.

```
$data = DB::table('data_reports')
    ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(id) as total, vendedor'))
    ->groupBy('vendedor');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query:

```
$results = DataReport::select(DB::raw('MAX(sub.total) as total, sub.vendedor'))
->from(function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('COUNT(id) as total, vendedor'))
        ->from('data_reports')
        ->groupBy('vendedor');
}, 'sub')
->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much arya_la. I modified it so that the result is of type 'Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder' and not 'Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder'